# Array of objects within class in PHP

Tags: php, class

I recently realized my currently approach on a project would greatly improve with the use of better/more descriptive objects. As such, I realized that I want an array of objects to be a member of another class.

Edit: I wasn't clear as to what my question was. My question is thus: How do I have an array in class LogFile that contains objects of type Match?

```
class LogFile
{
    public $formattedMatches;
    public $pathToLog;
    public $matchCount;
    ** An array called matches that is an array of objects of type Match **
}

class Match
{
    public $owner;
    public $fileLocation;
    public $matchType;
}
```

Eventually I want to be able to do something like:

```
$logFile = new LogFile();
$match = new Match();
$logFile->matches[$i]->owner = “Brian”;
```

How do I do what I described? In other words, what do I need to do in class `LogFile` to create an array that contains objects of type `Match`?

Comment: How do I do what I described? In other words, what do I need to do in class LogFile to create an array that contains objects of type Match?

Comment: Instead of commenting on all of the individual answers I just wanted to say thanks to all of you for your help. I see how it is now. The lack of strong formatting rules throws me off still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that would work.

```
class LogFile
{
    public $formattedMatches;
    public $pathToLog;
    public $matchCount;
    public $matches = array();
}

class Match
{
    public $owner;
    public $fileLocation;
    public $matchType;
}

$l = new LogFile();
$l->matches[0] = new Match();
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an addition to the [answer by Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812198/array-of-objects-within-class-in-php/7812271#7812271) or [by swatkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812198/array-of-objects-within-class-in-php/7812286#7812286). You wrote:

> what do I need to do in class LogFile to create an array that contains objects of type Match?

You can create an "array" that only can contain `Match` objects. This is fairly easy by extending from `ArrayObject` and only accepting object of a specific class:

```
class Matches extends ArrayObject
{
    public function offsetSet($name, $value)
    {
        if (!is_object($value) || !($value instanceof Match))
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Only objects of Match allowed.'));
        }
        parent::offsetSet($name, $value);
    }
}
```

You then make you class `LogFile` use that `Matches` class:

```
class LogFile
{
    public $formattedMatches;
    public $pathToLog;
    public $matchCount;
    public $matches;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->matches = new Matches();
    }
}
```

In the constructor you set it up, the new `Matches` "Array". Usage:

```
$l = new LogFile();
$l->matches[] = new Match(); // works fine

try
{
    $l->matches[] = 'test'; // throws exception as that is a string not a Match
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'There was an error: ', $e->getMessage();

}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/MUNw3gn7) - Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just create another public variable for matches.  Then, you can initialize it as an array in the [constructor method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

```
class LogFile
{
    public $formattedMatches;
    public $pathToLog;
    public $matchCount;
    public $matches;

    function __construct() {
        $matches=array();
        //Load $matches with whatever here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class LogFile
{
    public $formattedMatches;
    public $pathToLog;
    public $matchCount;
    public $matches = array();
}
```

PHP isn't strongly typed - you can put whatever you like in any variable.  To add to matches, just do `$logFile->matches[] = new Match();`.

Answer (score 0):

Just include

```
public $matches = array();
```

Then when you want to add to the the array:

```
$matches[] = $match;   // $match being object of type match
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object of [`SplObjectStorage`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) as this is intended to store objects.

Answer (score 0):

Create the array as public static:

```
public static $arr = array();
```

And then just push each new instance of the class into the array as they are constructed by adding the following line to your constructor:

```
array_push(yourClassHere:: $arr, $this);
```

You can then access the array globally, for instance:

```
print_r(YourClass:: $arr);
```

This will present you with an array of all objects created for that class.